# CSS div wrapping and vertical whitespace

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm attempting to have several div elements wrap to the next line when the width of its container is changed. The wrappings part works fine, the box will drop to the next line when there is not enought width for it to fit, however there is a gap between the first row element and the second row element if the heights are different. I would like in the following example for box b4 to slide up into the white space area under b1. Is this possible?  Thanks for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/86xcY/

Comment: You're looking for a masonry layout: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you ahren, indeed masonry is what I'm looking for. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
    hello one small changes  i this case you must set the min-height and  max-height     details as follows. and when you add the content the height automatically increased.


   #box3 {
    display: table-cell;
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 98px;
    width: 200px;
 }
```

Comment: ram thanks for taking a stab but that didn't seem to resolve my issue. Appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be close to what you're looking for. It could probably be optimized a lot, and tweaked to better suit your needs. Also, there is a bug when it goes to a single column that I can't be bothered to sort it. More than likely, the best solution to that will be just setting all `margin-top` values to `0` when under a certain screen width.

http://jsfiddle.net/86xcY/1/

```
$(window).resize(function(e){
    var wid = $("#container").width();

    $("#container .box").each(function(index, element){
        $(this).css("margin-top", 0);
        var top = $(this).position().top;
        var left = $(this).position().left;

        var upwards = null;
        var htm = $("html")[0];

        if (top > 0){
            var cTop = top;
            while ((upwards == null || upwards == htm) && cTop > 0){
                cTop -= 10;
                upwards = document.elementFromPoint(left, cTop);
            }
            var uTop = $(upwards).position().top;
            var uHei = $(upwards).height();

            var negMarg = (uTop + uHei) - top;

            if (negMarg < 0){
                $(this).css("margin-top", negMarg);
            }
            else if (negMarg > 0)
                $(this).css("margin-top", 0);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Also, that masonry link @ahren posted will probably be a better solution.

Comment: Shmiddty, appreciate you helping me out. I still see the gaps between rows in your sample which is what I was trying to resolve.  The masonry solution, like you said, seems to be a pretty good solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @zlspjp Yeah, my code doesn't actually do anything until you resize the window. You can force it to do it on the first run by using `$(window).resize();`, but as previously stated, the Masonry plugin seems like a much better solution. :)

Answer (score -2):

It is possible if you add a `float:left` to your elements.